# C# - Using HTMLAgilityPack to convert a Node to String

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, dom, selectsinglenode

I am trying to convert a selected span tag's inner text to a string.

```
<span id="course-text">ELEC1700/ELEC1700 2012 S1: Computer Engineering 1</span>
```

So the above would become: "ELEC1700/ELEC1700 2012 S1: Computer Engineering 1"

I have tried a couple of combinations using innerText and getAttributes, I just can't get it to work.

```
string name;

WebClient client = new WebClient();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

htmlDoc.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(client.DownloadString(urlTxtBx.Text)));

name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@id='course-text']").InnerText;
```

Comment: Are you loading the text from textbox? Try this if your using html - > htmlDocument.LoadHtml(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(htmlString))?

Comment: Have you confirmed the htmlDoc definitely contains the right xml (since it looks like you are getting it from the web... Does it work when you just put in the sample HTML directly (removing variables for the win).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the client.DownloadString on the urlTxtBx.Text.

Above code now works fine :)

Comment: if you use `htmlDoc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString(urlTxtBx.Text));` it saves you a stringreader ;-)